# Make GWT interact with ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, gwt

Does anyone know of a good article or tutorial on the Internet demonstrating the use of GWT leveraging a (ASP.NET) web service cross domain?

To my knowledge, interacting with either XML or JSON should be possible from GWT, but becomes a lot more difficult when the web service is on a different domain. I've tried finding an article that demonstrates this setup, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was initially going for a JSONP approach (as [suggested](http://code.google.com/intl/da/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/Xsite.html) by Google), in order to do cross site AJAX calls in JavaScript, but ended up with too many hacks that I had to incorporate into the ASP.NET web service in order for it to work.

The solution, in my case, was instead to use GWT RPC to a JAVA servlet, acting as a proxy, which then would call the ASP.NET Web Service using SOAP. The SOAP Java classes was generated using the wslist tool that is part of JAX-WS project (as demonstrated [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/edujini_webservice_java.aspx)).

Using the GWT RPC, I was still able to call the JAVA servlet asynchronously, giving the user a seamless experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options available:

- use the [Cross Site linker](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/LinkerDesign) - it should make cross domain request easier, simply add `<set-linker name="xs"/>` in your module file (*.gwt.xml)
- [window.name hack](http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-domain-formpanel-submissions-in.html) :) Be sure to read the post with the original [dojo proposal](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/)
- JSONP
- many others ;)

But first I recommend reading http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/Xsite.html - it should get you going :)