# GWT interface to Solr index

Tags: java, gwt, solr, same-origin-policy

I have a solr index on a remote server and need to create a search page interface. I am using GWT to code the pages and XML-HTTP to query the index and receive the response. The problem is the same-site origin security policy. It won't let JavaScript retrieve the remote XML data. Is there a workaround for this, without using JSON preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar problem: [Make GWT interact with ASP.NET Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488740/make-gwt-interact-with-asp-net-web-service)

The answers there should also apply here.

Depending on the type of data that you want to send (that is, how "public" they are), **JSONP** might not be the best option - it's not the safest method of transport (pure **JSON** is safer, but to overcome SOP you need the padding).

If you have a Java server on the.. server side, I'd go with `GWT <-> servlet (acting as proxy, on the same domain as your main app) <-> web service (any domain)` - the safest and cleanest code, afaict.

Comment: Yes, that links sums it up quite well. The name trick is interesting and should work on multiple browser types. The proxy is the easiest solution.

Comment: The `window.name` hack is also much safer than `JSONP` - the only voulnerability I know of is that the value of `window.name` persists, even if the user leaves the site (that's why this hack works, but that also means that sitexxx.com could try to read window.name in search of confidential/any data). However, using that custom `FormPanel` from Ray Cromwell fixes that - the `FormPanel` uses a dynamically created iframe, so after use it's discarded and thus afterward no one can read the value of `window.name` of that iframe.

Comment: thanks igro. i'm implementing a java servlet on the server since i already have tomcat running.